# conditional density function with respect to a statistic.

Tags: probability

I have read a formula in a textbook:
$$f_{Y|S}(y|s;\theta)=\frac{f_Y(y;\theta)}{f_S(s;\theta)}$$
$Y$ is a random vector and $S$ is a statistic of $Y$.

According to the definition of conditional density function,why the numerator not be $f_{Y,S}(y,s|\theta)$ the joint density function?
 [image]

[image]

Comment: $S$ is a statistic of $Y$, so what about the distribution of $S|Y=y$?

Comment: @Augustin you mean Y|S=y?

Comment: Why I can't add the "conditional probability" tag?